# SQL Server perform a delete on all child records when deleting from a parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have 3 tables:

```
Create TABLE Subjects
(
    SubjectID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    SubjectName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ClassID VARCHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Classes(ClassID) NOT NULL
);

Create TABLE Topic
( 
    TopicID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    TopicName VARCHAR(100),
    SubjectID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Subjects(SubjectID)
); 

Create Table Worksheet
(
    WorksheetName varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY,
    TopicID INT Foreign KEY References Topic(TopicID),
    Num_Q INT NOT NULL,
    W_Type varchar(30)
);
```

Each one is a one to many relationship. When I try to delete from Subjects I get a foreign key constraint which is fine. What I want to know is how to get around this and perform a query to delete all relating aspects in a cascading style. I looked it up and there's but I am not sure how it works there seems to be multiple queries. Would it be better to create a trigger or is there a basic cascading function to do it all? I'm using visual studio to perform queries but not sure where the options to perform tasks like this are?

Comment: You want `on delete cascade` as part of the foreign key relationship.  Here is a reasonable explanation:  http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `ON DELETE CASCADE` right after the foreign key definition:

```
Create TABLE Subjects (
    SubjectID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    SubjectName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ClassID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Classes(ClassID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

You can also define it as a separate constraint, if you like, either within the `CREATE TABLE` statement or using `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the DDL for your `Topic` table with a `CASCADE` for delete. Its just a matter of defining it in your FK but using [a slightly different syntax](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php). This is for MS Sql Server.

```
CREATE TABLE Topic
( 
    TopicID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    TopicName VARCHAR(100),
    SubjectID INT, 
    CONSTRAINT FK_Subjects_Topic FOREIGN KEY (SubjectID)
        REFERENCES Subjects (SubjectID) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

**EDIT** - added `DELETE CASCADE` on Worksheet table based on comment feedback.

```
Create Table Worksheet
(
    WorksheetName varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY,
    TopicID INT,
    Num_Q INT NOT NULL,
    W_Type varchar(30),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Topic_Worksheet FOREIGN KEY (TopicID)
        REFERENCES Topic (TopicID) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

With this updated definition a delete on table `Subjects` will also delete child records in table `Topics`.

Comment: I added a on Delete Cascade to both Topic and Subjects as it wasn't working with just Topic but I'm getting this back:  Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 116
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__Worksheet__Topic__5A846E65". The conflict occurred in database "cosy", table "dbo.Worksheet", column 'TopicID'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @ecribs - you have to add this across your table relationships. So if you have constraints that continue down from Topics to Worksheets then you need to ensure that the FK defined there is also marked as Cascade (if that is the expected behavior). I edited the answer to also specify a `CASCADE DELETE` from Topics to Worksheet.