# Manually delete cascade on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of tables (SQL Server 2014) and I need to perform a delete cascade but manually. I have these three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.A
(
    IdKey int identity primary Key,
    Name nvarchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.B
(
    Id int identity primary Key,
    ChildIdKey int,
    Name nvarchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.C
(
    Id int identity primary Key,
    OtherIdKey int,
    Name nvarchar(50)
)
```

If I need to remove IdKey from table A, I need first to identify the foreign keys pointed to IdKey on table A. I have a FK over ChildIdKey on table B and another on FK over OtherIdKey on table C. Column names are different so now I need to get all tables where I have a FK pointed to IdKey and perform a delete cascade manually and in order to avoid FK errors.

How can I get the list of tables in the correct order for performing the cascade delete manually?

Comment: Why don't you add the fk's to the create table statements?

Comment: Do you need an automated solution? Because what I usually do in such cases (`CASCADE` missing) is delete the rows from `A`, observe that I get an error telling me that rows in `B` are referencing it, delete rows in `B`... this process usually terminates quickly. An automated solution involves writing a recursive query and is definitely more trouble than it's worth if this is a one-time action (which it should be, per database, if the structure doesn't change).

Comment: it's just an example

Comment: it has to be something dynamically, I don't want to receive any error when I'm deleting from table A

Comment: You have 2 options. 1. Either you specify the cascade delete option and let your schema handle the deletes automatically for you OR 2. you do it yourself manually in your code (sql or calling code). There is probably a way to retrieve all the FK constraints and build a sql statement that way but all you are doing then is recreating option 1 but manually and much more inefficient.

Comment: If you are looking on how to implement ON DELETE CASCADE then this is probably [a duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35814287/1260204)

Comment: your database model, explanation and question are all very odd. You should come back with your real problem because we don't understand anything ...

Comment: You will have to look at sys.foreignkeys and sys.foreign_key_columns if you want to do this dynamically. It will require dynamic sql and far more effort than it is worth. With a proper database model this shouldn't be needed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find out all table depending on a particular column of some-table

```
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname,@TableName sysname
SET @ColumnName='userId'
SET @TableName='user'  


SELECT  Fkn.name FKName ,
cname.name FKColumnName,
        FCT.name FKContainingTable ,
        CCT.name ColumnContainingTable
FROM    sys.foreign_key_columns Fk
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fkn ON fkn.object_id=fk.constraint_object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.tables FCT ON fCt.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.tables CCT ON fk.referenced_object_id = CCT.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns CLM ON CCT.object_id = clm.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns CName ON CName.object_id=fk.parent_object_id AND CName.column_id=fk.parent_column_id
                                      AND CLM.name = @ColumnName 
                                      AND cct.name = @TableName
```